# dynamic template based on $routeProvider resolves

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I've got a url in my application that needs to load one of two templates based on the results of a resolve call, like so:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/someurl', {
            resolve: {
                someData: function(dataService) {
                    var data = dataService.loadData();

                    // data has a .type field that determines which template should be loaded

                    return data;
                }
            },
            templateUrl: function(routeParams) {
                // return a path based on the value of data.type in the someData resolve block
            }
        })
});
```

Is there a way for me to set the templateUrl based on what's returned by the someData resolve?

Comment: Is there a reason not to just make two different routes and have the resolve redirect to the other one if needed? By the way, `ui-router` is considered a far better choice for Angular routers, even by the Angular/ngRoute developers.

Comment: Basically, I'm displaying data about an item (which required a different controller depending on the item type), and I want to be able to have this work without needing to put the item type in the url.

Comment: There are plenty of ways you could go about that, I think. For example, you could set a service variable from the resolve, then have the controller/template that gets instantiated respond accordingly. It's just a bit messier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to do this using ui-router - thanks m59 for pointing me at it.

Here's how you'd do this with ui-router:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('someState'
            url: '/someurl',
            template: '<ui-view>',
            resolve: {
                someData: function(dataService) {
                    var data = dataService.loadData();

                    // data has a .type field that determines which template should be loaded

                    return data;
                }
            },
            controller: function($state, someData) {
                $state.go('someState.' + someData.type);
            }
        })
        .state('someState.type1', {
            templateUrl: 'someTemplate1.html',
            controller: 'Type1Controller'
        })
        .state('someState.type2', {
            templateUrl: 'someTemplate2.html',
            controller: 'Type2Controller'
        })
});
```

There's a parent state that handles resolves, then redirects to the child states based on the information it gets. The child states don't have a url, so they can't be loaded directly.

Comment: I wonder if today there is a solution for this in the regular router or if using ui-router has become a necessity (without using ng-include in the template and setting that in the controller).